# Import at file level inside a function? (Python 2)

Tags: python, import

Is it possible to do something like this?

```
def loadModules():
  import time
  from myModule import *

def runFunction():
  try:
    print str(time.time())
    print myFunction() # myFunction is in myModule (myModule.myFunction)
  except NameError:
    raise RuntimeError("Module was not initialized. Call loadModules() first.")

if (__name__ == "__main__"):
  # this should fail
  try:
    runFunction()
  except RuntimeError:
    print "Exception raised as expected."

  loadModules()

  runFunction() # it should work now
```

This will not work as expected because importing the modules *inside* the loadModules function will not declare them at a file level.

For modules like `time` I could add a `global time` statement after the import. However, how can I accomplish this for a situation where the items imported are unknown, as in `from myModule import *`? I won't automatically know the name of every function in `myModule`. And even if I did, that'd be an ugly global statement.

Essentially, can I basically take all local variables and make them global?

EDIT: This seemed to work in test code:

```
def test():
    import time
    global time
    print "Inside test function: %s" % str(time.time())

test()
print "outside function: %s" % str(time.time())
```

This also worked:

```
def test():
    from time import time
    global time
    print "Inside test function: %s" % str(time())

test()
print "outside function: %s" % str(time())
```

This however did not work:

```
def test():
    import time
    print "Inside test function: %s" % str(time.time())

test()
print "outside function: %s" % str(time.time())
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a horrible idea, even if it could ever work, which it couldn't.

Putting a `global` statement after the import will have exactly zero effect. The only thing that does is mark that name as global *within the current scope*. Once the function returns, the caller will still have no knowledge of the imported names.

In any case, you shouldn't ever be using `from MyModule import *` anyway.

Comment: `global` is having some kind of effect... See original post. Additionally, MyModule is my own library, and I am maintaining all of its functions, so in this instance it doesn't seem to be as bad of an idea. Doing it from unknown or large libraries is a bad idea agreed.